# HTML FORMS - How do you ask for input to be in a specific format? (Discord name#ID format)

Tags: html, forms, web, format, specifications

## This is a part of my form:

```
<input class="input-text" type="text" pattern=".+#.+" name="Name-hash-ID" placeholder="Your name + # + four digit number ID*"/>
```

I want the user to write down in this specific format:

his username + # + number

But I also have some more specifications... I need the user's number to be 4 DIGITS exactly and the username to be between 2-12 characters only. Also to separate the number and name, user must also have a HASHTAG between...

How do you use the pattern attribute in this scenario? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following pattern:

```
.+#\d{4}
```